# Antonym of nature, that implies the cities and infrastructure constructed by man

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I want to use a **noun** to describe the buildings and roads etc constructed by man ... as opposed to the forest and sea that exist on Earth naturally. Something besides "man-made".

ETA: Many of the answers take the examples too literally. I mean to say *everything* constructed or caused by humans. Not specifically the roads and buildings, not a particular object, nothing in context of a city, or organisation.

I want a generalised term, but also not a collective noun like 'assemblage' ... like nature implies everything not created by us and isn't a collective noun.

A word that can fit into this sentence :
"I took a brief retreat from (the) ______ (created by man) to enjoy the Earth gifted to us by Nature."

Comment: The Earth describes the planet in its natural state. The World describes human habitation with all its accoutrements. (I would suggest.)

Comment: Terms like "the urban world" or "the built environment" come to mind.

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus? start with antonyms of 'natural' or synonyms of 'artificial'

Comment: A synonym of artificial that can be used as a noun is what I'm looking for.  I've checked the MW thesaurus.

Comment: In response to a deleted answer that mentioned the word "construct" ... I'm looking for a generalisation of all such "constructs". Like "nature" is a generalisation of all the (natural!) ecosystems around us.

Comment: You assume that 'nature' is natural today. After Rene Dubois who asked, "What is nature?" that is controversial. Otherwise, would *infrastructure* work?

Comment: You may assume that 'nature' comprises of everything that humans have not constructed or caused. No philosophy involved.

Comment: If I were to write a question asking for a word that means our natural surroundings, anything that is not artificial or made by man. The answer would be "nature", likewise the answer to your question is "man-made". Please explain why you have discarded this perfectly acceptable and universally known term.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A ...read "noun" and the FITB sentence

Comment: Hmm, there's "concrete," as in "concrete jungle."  There's also "parking lot," as in, "They paved paradise and put up a parking lot."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Civilization* would seem to fit your example.

As in, "I took a brief retreat from civilization to enjoy the Earth gifted to us by Nature."

Answer (score 2):

the built environment

> built environment
>  noun
>  Man-made structures, features, and
>   facilities viewed collectively as an environment in which people live
>   and work.
>  ‘architects who are helping to shape the built
>   environment in this newly prominent region’
>  [Oxford Living
>   Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/built_environment)
>
> the built environment
>  the buildings and all other things
>   constructed by human beings 
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-built-environment)
>
> the built environment
>  noun
>  all the structures people have
>   built when considered as separate from the natural environment
>   [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the-built-environment)
>
> In social science, the term built environment, or built world, refers
>   to the human-made surroundings that provide the setting for human
>   activity, ranging in scale from buildings to parks.
>   [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Built_environment)

You can also go with artifact. Artifacts are things made by humans.

> n.
>   1. An object produced or shaped by human craft, especially a tool, weapon, or ornament of archaeological or historical interest.
>   2. Something viewed as a product of human conception or agency rather than an inherent element
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/artifact)

Comment: "the built environment" is a phrase - accurate, but still not one word. Like, saying, "I took a brief retreat from the built environment" sounds awkward and mechanical. "Artifact" refers to a singular object.

Comment: @ProgramSpree Not sure, maybe "I left the monotonous concrete jungle for a much needed nature retreat." concrete jungle is informal. Oops, still not one word.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try *[infrastructure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infrastructure)*.

noun
1.3 the system of public works of a country, state, or region; also : the resources (such as personnel, buildings, or equipment) required for an activity

"Infra- means 'below;' so the infrastructure is the 'underlying structure' of a country and its economy, the fixed installations that it needs in order to function. These include roads, bridges, dams, the water and sewer systems, railways and subways, airports, and harbors. These are generally government-built and publicly owned."

Comment: Infrastructure implies a system in context of its relevance to the organization - a country or company or a certain product. It isn't exactly a direct antonym of "nature".

Answer (score 0):

**assemblage**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/assemblage)

> the act or process of assembling or the state of being assembled;
>   things gathered or collected; an assembly; collection; aggregate.

As in:

> Humanity's **assemblage** besmirches Earth.

Answer (score 0):

On a smaller scale, in particular materials, I think of **synthetic**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/synthetic.):

> Synthetic products are made from artificial substances, often copying a natural product

In your case you could say:

> Many of today's roads are made with asphalt, a **synthetic** material.

Attribution: "Synthetic Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed April 04, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/synthetic.